# Take action on sustained touch instead of just when getting touchesBegan:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing a game and when a user touches the left or right side of the screen, a "sustain level" is increased. Currently the increase only happens when the user first touches the screen (my code is below). I want the increase to be applied for as long as the user holds their finger on the screen.  What do I have to do?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

      if (self.x >= touchPoint.x){
          self.sustain += 1;

      }else if (self.x <= touchPoint.x){
          self.sustain += 1;

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> increased.Currently the sustain level only increase when you first touch the screen, I want the force to be applied for as long as the user holds their finger on the screen

You won't get any messages while the user holds the finger still; your next message will be `touchesEnded`. So you need to start a *timer* and just keep increasing the force as desired every time the timer fires, until you get `touchesEnded`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out how rapidly you want this increase to happen. Then use a timer mechanism to change the value. This could be an `NSTimer` that fires repeatedly on a certain interval: you start the timer when you get `touchesBegan:` and stop it when you get `touchesEnded:`

If you're using SpriteKit, the scene has a built-in timer that triggers its `update:` method. You can use a flag to indicate that a touch is present and change the "sustain" value in `update:`.